# Partial View models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, layout, razor

Within my layout page, I want to either show a Login box, OR the details about the logged in person.

```
<div>
        @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            @Html.ViewBag.UserDisplay
            @Html.ActionLink("[Logout]", "LogoutUser", "User")
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Partial("_Login")
        }
        <hr />
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
```

My login partial view:

```
@model BasicFinanceUI.Models.LoginModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginUser", "User"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        Username: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username) 
        Password: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password) 
        Remember Me: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RememberMe, new[]
                {
                    new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "true"},
                    new SelectListItem() {Text = "No", Value = "false"}
                }, "Select")

        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        @Html.ActionLink("[Register]", "Register", "User")
    </p>

}
```

When I load the screen, and login, it works fine.

However, when I click 'Register', it loads the register screen. The login box is still visible in the Layout.

My registration screen is displayed:

```
@model BasicFinanceUI.Models.RegisterationModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/SiteLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Register</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "User"))
{
    <p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>

    <p>Username: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)</p>
    <p>Password: @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password1)</p>
    <p>Retype Password: @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password2)</p>
    <p>Firstname: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Firstname)</p>
    <p>Surname: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Surname)</p>
    <p>Email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p>

    <p><input type="submit" value="Register"/></p>
}
```

When I click the Register button, things go wrong.

I get the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'BasicFinanceUI.Models.RegisterationModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type 'BasicFinanceUI.Models.LoginModel'.

It seems because there are two forms on the screen, they're getting mixed up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The easiest fix would be to pass an empty `LoginModel` to your partial: `@Html.Partial("_Login", new LoginModel())`...

Comment: That worked - is it the right way though? If so, problem solved!

Comment: @Craig yes it is the right way, I do it all the time.

Comment: @nemesv you should add that as an answer so Craig can mark it as correct.